# Android ImageView centerCrop not working. Skewing instead of scaling

Tags: android, imageview, scale, crop

I'm currently working on a Navigation Drawer where I want the user photo to be scaled, cropped, tinted, then used as the header image behind a circular crop of there picture.

I can't even post images because this account is too low rep...damn me and using my old student account for most of my questions...

Despite my `ImageView` being defined like this

```
<ImageView
    android:tint="@color/clyp_copy"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/pixplogo"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

[This image (1) skews like this (2) (Same link, two images)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpLD6.jpg)

This is actually a common issue for me. I've never gotten `centerCrop` to work properly. I don't understand why.

Testing on 5.1.1, building on SDK 23. Same issue on 21

[Not sure if this is allowed on SO, but here's a Debug apk...maybe it's just my device...or 5.x](http://puu.sh/kqAiY/4a37952996.apk)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Replace

```
android:background="@drawable/pixplogo"
```

with

```
android:src="@drawable/pixplogo"
```

Comment: This has happened to me more times than I'm proud to admit.

Comment: @McSullivanD'Ander same here, that's how I knew what to look for  :)