# Image ignores scaleType when put inside CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to only show part of the image inside a CollapsingToolbarLayout as a background when the toolbar is "expanded" but no matter what scaleType and size I put for the `ImageView`, it looks exactly the same every time.

**When I try to scale:**

[image: Image not scaling]

activity_profile.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="co.magnt.classmagnet.ProfileActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_picture"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/default_avatar"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

I would really appreciate any help with my issue!

EDIT: I want it the image to look something like this

[image: Look like this]

Comment: I have currently the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: found the solution there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32814207/1768839

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` on the imageview?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds

Comment: What about setting the height to `wrap_contents` instead of `match_parent`?